# (JDBC) Mysql query with if statement and multiple conditions

Tags: java, mysql, sql

What is the proper syntax for a mysql-java statement such as this one ?

```
PreparedStatement st =connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Name, Value, Quantity FROM sales if (type=='Purchase' AND state=='confirmed') OR (type=='Sale' AND state=='not confirmed'))  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL would look like:

```
SELECT Name, Value, Quantity
FROM sales 
WHERE (type = 'Purchase' AND state = 'confirmed') OR
      (type = 'Sale' AND state = 'not confirmed');
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be in a `where clause, not an`if`clause, and the equality check operator in SQL is`=`, not`==`. So:

```
SELECT Name, Value, Quantity 
FROM   sales 
WHERe  (type = 'Purchase' AND state = 'confirmed') OR 
       (type = 'Sale' AND state = 'not confirmed')
```